# error: cannot find symbol superclass and subclass

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

I am a beginner in java and I am trying to write a java code where the program has to calculate the arithmetic mean in the superclass and standard deviation in the subclass.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
class ArithmeticMean
{
    double  sum=0, mean, variance, sd, vsum;
    double a[] = new double[10];
    int n,i;
    void accept()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many Numbers do you want to enter?");
        n=scanner.nextInt();

        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter No ["+(i+1)+"] : ");
            a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }       
    }
    void calculate()
    {
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + a[i];
            mean = sum/n;
        }
    }
}
class StandardDeviation extends ArithmeticMean
{
    void calculateSd()
    {
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            vsum = vsum+((a[i]-mean)*(a[i]-mean));
            variance = vsum/(n-1);
            sd=Math.sqrt(variance);
        }
    }
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Arithmetic mean = "+mean);
        System.out.println("Variance = "+variance);
        System.out.println("Standard Deviation = "+sd);
    }
}
class u3Program9
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        StandardDeviation s = new StandardDeviation();
        s.accept();
        s.calculate();
        s.calculateSD();
        s.display();
    }
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: You should Use some IDE like eclipse to write program such type of syntex error wont occur.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Answer (score 1):

Java is case-sensitive programming language.

> You have defined `calculateSd()` in StandardDeviation class and invoking `calculateSD()` on instance of StandardDeviation `s.calculateSD()`. Where it should be accesed as `s.calculateSd()`

Answer (score 1):

your method is declared as `calculateSd`,

in your main method change

```
s.calculateSD();
```

to

```
s.calculateSd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You failed type method name.
Your method in StandardDeviation class: `calculateSd`.
You invoke method: `calculateSD`.

You need rewrite method number to upper or lower case.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that it cannot find the symbol named 'calculateSD()' in s of StandardDeviation class.

That gives a clue. The method is defined as 'calculateSd()' in StandardDeviation.class, with the lower-case 'd' in the back.